# LineSeries setHighlightOnHover, onHover, onMouseClick doesn't work

Tags: lightningchart

On LightningtChartJS, I added 2 LineSeries which displays correctly (screenshot).
[sample line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Wjy.png)

Then I am trying to do the highlighting of the lines on hover, plus the hover and mouseclick events.

I set the following:

```
const series=this.chart.addLineSeries({});
series.add(data); //data var is set above this code

series.setHighlightOnHover(true);
    
series.onHover((...args)=>{
   console.log(args);
});
series.onMouseClick((...args)=>{
   console.log(args);
});
```

The the highlight doesn't work, hover and click events don't trigger when I hover or click on a any of the lines.

Please help.

Comment: Seems that this feature is not working on the 3.0 version.
It should be fixed in a patch or minor release in the near future. 

To try it out immediately you can revert to previous version, and it should work out of the box - highlighting on hover is enabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that this feature is not working on the 3.0 version. It should be fixed in a patch or minor release in the near future. To try it out immediately you can revert to previous version, and it should work out of the box - highlighting on hover is enabled by default.

**EDIT: v3.0.1** has just been released along with fixes to this issue.

In this version, LineSeries mouse interactions are disabled by default because they don't perform well in all cases. **In order for mouse interactions to work you must enable them with `setMouseInteractions(true)`.**

The mentioned performance issues can happen with FREEFORM line series and large amount of data (~hundreds of thousands of data points). If you are using a progressive data pattern then there are no issues.

**EDIT: v3.4**

The general situation is still the same, the mouse interactions of Line Series are still disabled by default and you must enable them with `setMouseInteractions(true)`. Furthermore, highlighting on hover is also disabled by default, and must be enabled with `setHighlightOnHover(true)`.

Following snippet is confirmed to work in online examples:

```
const series = chart.addLineSeries({
    dataPattern: {
        pattern: 'ProgressiveX',
        regularProgressiveStep: true,
    }
 })
    .setHighlightOnHover(true)
    .setMouseInteractions(true)
    
series.onHover((...args)=>{
   console.log(args);
});
series.onMouseClick((...args)=>{
   console.log(args);
});
```

**However,** something of an extra complication is the automatic disabling of mouse interactions during animations and scrolling, which is enabled by default. These can be disabled as follows:

```
chart
    .setMouseInteractionsWhileScrolling(true)
    .setMouseInteractionsWhileZooming(true)
```

Thankfully we are just about to move into a breaking version release v4.0.0 where we can properly resolve the situation. Stay tuned for improvements regarding mouse interactions in the coming months.

Comment: Is this broken on 3.4.0 again?

Comment: It doesn't even work on the online tutorials

Comment: Mouse interactions are working on v3.4.0 and online tutorials. Updated the answer with updated information.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was missing the setMouseInteractions(true), it is working since I added that.